# Ruby on Rails 3 modeling complex medical questionnaire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I need to convert a medical questionnaire into an online version. I have looked at Surveyor[1](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor)
, but the issue with mine is that there a lot of different "tests" or "exams" that require precise answers. For example, if the questions are about blood tests, then the user needs to enter measurements. Should I just model each test or exam separately, or is there a smarter way to do this? I would say that about half are simply yes/no/unknown type questions, and the half require entering measurements. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar issue when creating a customer survey system for a client.  Our issue was that the client needed the ability to create survey's on their own in the future - meaning anything we implemented couldn't be hard coded like you mentioned as an option for you.

In our case, while there were a couple of different scenarios they would encounter, it really wouldn't change all THAT much - it really boiled down to number answers, text answers, ranges, etc...

We added a "style" field to our questions model and implemented validations based on the style that was selected for it.  So a "number" question would check for numerical answers, etc...  We also implemented the validations client-side using js, just so they'd have more upfront info on if their answers were sufficient (time saving seems important in a medical application).  It worked well for our needs - hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested attributes like in this episode : http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised. You have other episodes here : http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested+form